# Javascript how to properly clone and not modify an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, lodash

I have an object, which i search the keys and modify the values if a key match is found:

```
var myData = // some http.get which returns a JSON object.
```

Imagine myData is:

```
myData : {
    "suffix" : "mr",
    "fname" : "jullian",
    "lname" : "exor",
    "dobGmt" : 145754294700000
    "addressLine1" : "xxx",
    "street" : "xxx",
    "rentStartedGmt" : 145754294700000,
    "deposit" : "50.00",
    "occupation" : "math teacher",
    "profession" : {
         "careerStartedGmt": 1458755224800000,
         "careerEndGmt": 1459854224800000,
     }
}

$scope.viewData = function() {
    var objClone = _.clone(myData);
    objClone = myFactory.ProcessData(objClone);
    $scope.view = objClone;
};

$scope.viewProducts = function() {

};
```

MyFactory:

```
myModule.factory('myFactory', function() {
    return {
        ProcessData: function(data) {
            var tmp = data;

            function findGmt(tmp) {
                for (var key in tmp) {
                    var v = tmp[key];
                        if (key.indexOf("Gmt") !== -1) {
                            tmp[key] = tmp[key].format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm');    
                        }    
                    }
                }

            findGmt(tmp);

            return tmp;
        }
    }
});
```

User can click on `viewData` button which calls `$scope.viewData` which displays the formatted JSON in a modal on the same page.
User then clicks on `viewProducts` which calls `$scope.viewProducts` which displays a list of products in a modal on the same page.

However, after clicking `viewProducts`, if i go back to click `viewData` **again**, on debugging, i can see var `objClone` is already formatted, rather than taking a new clone of _.clone(myData);

Have a missed how to clone/not modifiy original objects?

Comment: @evolutionxbox duplicate in context, not helpful when the op asked for a totally different language.

Comment: @Val - my bad - removed

Comment: I personal would try this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object (which is `.extend` but not sure about if reference is lost or not as you have asked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, [clone functions](https://lodash.com/docs#clone) (that can now be replaced by the standard [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)) only copy the provided object properties into a new object. They do not recursively clone the values of the object. That means that the content of your `profession` property, for example, is the same object for the cloned and the original: `myData.profession === objClone.profession` is true.

What you are looking for is a [deep clone](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `var copiedObj = angular.copy(myObj)`. It will create copy of the myObj but changing myObj won't change anything in copiedObj.